# Python: merging multiple text files

Tags: python, csv, pandas, merge

I am new to Python, and not much of a coder. I have 40+ text files that I want to combine together (in a 'wide' csv, as opposed to a 'tall' csv. That is, I don't want to append the files) and produce a new csv.

Using Pandas (merge) I am able to achieve what I want, but I presume there is a simpler way. Here it is on seven of the files:

---

import pandas as pd

```
a = pd.read_csv("c:/pyTest/B01001.txt")
b = pd.read_csv("c:/pyTest/B01002.txt")
c = pd.read_csv("c:/pyTest/B01003.txt")
d = pd.read_csv("c:/pyTest/B02001.txt")
e = pd.read_csv("c:/pyTest/B05001.txt")
f = pd.read_csv("c:/pyTest/B05002.txt")
g = pd.read_csv("c:/pyTest/B05012.txt")

merged = a.merge(b.merge(c.merge(d.merge(e.merge(f.merge(g, on='GEOID'), on='GEOID'), on='GEOID'), on='GEOID'), on='GEOID'), on='GEOID')
merged.to_csv("c:/pytest/fook.csv", index=False)
```

---

It would be great if the duplicated column names (eg 'GEOID') weren't repeated in the output file too.

Any help from you experts greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show me an example of how two of the files look (just a single row) and how you would like them to end out? I dont follow your 'tall'/'wide' anology.

Comment: I think this is very similar to what you want to do?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689453/how-can-i-merge-two-csv-files-by-a-common-column-in-the-case-of-unequal-rows

Answer (score 2):

You can apply `merge` to a list of DataFrames [using reduce](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce):

```
import pandas as pd
import functools

files = ["c:/pyTest/B01001.txt", "c:/pyTest/B01002.txt", "c:/pyTest/B01003.txt",
         "c:/pyTest/B02001.txt", "c:/pyTest/B05001.txt", "c:/pyTest/B05002.txt",
         "c:/pyTest/B05012.txt",]
dfs = [pd.read_csv(filename).set_index('GEOID') for filename in files]
mergefunc = functools.partial(pd.merge, left_index=True, right_index=True)
merged = functools.reduce(mergefunc, dfs)

merged.to_csv("c:/pytest/fook.csv", index=False)
```

When Pandas merges two DataFrames based on the *index* (rather than on columns), the resultant DataFrame uses the merged index. Thus you can avoid duplication of GEOID columns by merging on the index.

---

For example:

```
In [99]: import numpy as np
In [100]: import pandas as pd
In [101]: import functools

In [102]: dfs = [pd.DataFrame(np.arange(6).reshape(3,2), columns=['A','B{}'.format(i)]).set_index('A') for i in range(3)]

In [103]: mergefunc = functools.partial(pd.merge, left_index=True, right_index=True)    
In [104]: merged = functools.reduce(mergefunc, dfs)

In [105]: merged
Out[105]: 
   B0  B1  B2
A            
0   1   1   1
2   3   3   3
4   5   5   5
```